# CodeIgniter and MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I've started to construct my own db class; where should I put this new db.php file? Do I `include('wherever/db.php')` in the model from where I plan to run queries?

Comment: CodeIgniter has excellent documentation, I suggest you start there. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: The documentation for the current version of CodeIgnigher is at [http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/)

Comment: @Wolf, thanks. Should I ignore the warning about not replacing database classes? So far, I was able to put in libraries and load it in my model and run a query.

Answer (score 0):

So something **VERY** obvious I just found was to use the sqlsrv not mssql db drivers as I was before resorting to writing my own db code. I was able resolve my main issue without having to write custom code for my database connection.

But thanks to the comments above by @Wolf and @DFriend, I learned so much more.